# How to handle ManyToOne relationships when it comes to update/delete records

Tags: c#, sql

I have an Order table, and a Coverage Table.

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Coverage (
`label` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`value` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
`orderId` NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY --Which is also a foreign key
);
```

In my front-end, I have a list of values, which represents coverages data, which is sent to the back end to be saved in the Coverage table.

Now my question is how should I handle the list of data? Since I send the list of data, if I delete a row in the front-end, how my back-end will know that I deleted a row? Should I delete all records and inserting the new list (I don't think that's the best choice).

Comment: If UI deletes an order - delete data from `Order` and updata all rows with that orderid in coverage table to null. If UI deletes an coverage, simply remove it from coverage table - you dont have to delete from order table.

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi What values are stored in the front end? Are you displaying all available `Coverage` records?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Speaking about deleting a coverage, the thing is that I only send the data when I submit the form, and the data is the list of coverage. So the deleted line won't be in the data. Should I send a request every time i delete a coverage to delete it from database ?

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes I am displaying all available coverage, since there will never be that much, and it's an internal tool. The value stored in front is a list of coverage object, so an object with a label, a value and an orderId.

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi What if two users submit the coverages at the same time? Say user 1 deletes a record of A and user 2 deletes a record of C. On user 1's submission A is deleted, but in user 2's submission record A is added?? Seems like you could be dealing with dirty data. This is assuming both users loaded the coverage data before any modifications were made.

Comment: @RyanWilson Indeed, you are right, how would you do to handle that ?

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi Does a user have the ability to add a record or only delete?

Comment: @RyanWilson Add, delete, update

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi Do all 3 actions take place through the same form? Or is there a way for you to determine the action they are taking on each record?

Comment: @RyanWilson Currently all the actions take place in the same form submition. But I can know which action is taken between deletion, creation and update

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi Are you using a `stored procedure` or ORM framework like `entity framework` to work on your database?

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, I use `entity framework`

Comment: @YounesGuarssifi Then I would think if you know for each row, if it's an `add, update, or delete` that you should be able to do the deletion by using the primary key of the `Coverage` to `delete` where `Coverage` `not in` `Coverage values` sent to the server.